# WPF host for Powershell, output formatting

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, powershell

**Description of Issue**:
I've created a host for Powershell 2.0. The host uses WPF and C#.

The problem is, much output to my WPF host is not formatted the same way as what is displayed when using Powershell ISE.

When I run the script `ls alias:` in Powershell ISE, the results are in a table form, with *CommandType*, *Name*, and *Definition* column headers. When I run the same script in my WPF host, the results are simply a list of the names of aliases. A similar issue happens with many other scripts, commandlets, and aliases.

**Question**:
How do I get the same formatting functionality that seems to be built into Powershell ISE? Is this an issue with the Powershell side of things, or do I need to include extra code on the WPF side of things?

**Code Sample**:
Here is the class I've built to handle Powershell input and output, from within WPF (framework courtesy of example at [code.msdn.microsoft.com](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-PowerShell-Host03-dd4e564a), although my class is *not* asynchronous):

```
internal class PSInterfacer
{
    private Runspace runspace { get; set; }

    public PSInterfacer()
    {
        runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
    }

    public string RunScript(string script)
    {
        string tempOut = "";
        // create powershell instance
        using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            // add existing runspace
            ps.Runspace = runspace;
            // add script
            ps.AddScript(script);
            // pipe errors to the same output as normal results
            ps.Commands.Commands[0].MergeMyResults(PipelineResultTypes.Error,
                PipelineResultTypes.Output);
            // put output in list
            List<PSObject> psOutputs = ps.Invoke().ToList();
            // display output elements, seperated by newlines
            foreach (PSObject psObject in psOutputs)
            {
                if (psObject != null)
                {
                    tempOut += psObject.BaseObject;
                }
                if (psObject != psOutputs.Last())
                {
                    tempOut += Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            return tempOut;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that just piped through [`Format-List`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849957.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working for a few days, found this solution. Basically, use the `.AddCommand` method (in the `Powershell` class) to pipe to "Out-String." That formats everything properly.

Replace `RunScript` method with this:

```
public string RunScript(string script)
{
    string tempOut = "";
    try
    {
        using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            ps.Runspace = runspace;
            ps.AddScript(script);
            ps.AddCommand("Out-String");
            ps.Commands.Commands[0].MergeMyResults(PipelineResultTypes.Error, PipelineResultTypes.Output);
            List<PSObject> psOutputs = ps.Invoke().ToList();
            foreach (PSObject psObject in psOutputs)
            {
                if (psObject != null)
                {
                    tempOut += psObject.BaseObject;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        tempOut = string.Format("Error when invoking powershell commands:\n{0}", ex.Message);
        tempOut += "\nThis function did not complete.";
    }
    return tempOut;
}
```